# Ethernet does not work when Wifi is on - macOS Mojave

Tags: networking, mac, macos-mojave

I've following case:

when Wifi on my MacBook is enabled, then Ethernet interface does not work (Mac is not ARPing). How to fix it?

WIFI on:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            192.168.55.1       UGScg             en0       
127                localhost          UCS               lo0       
localhost          localhost          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#14            UCS               en0      !
169.254            link#24            UCSI              en7      !
192.168.1          link#24            UCS               en7      !
192.168.1.1        link#24            UHRLWI            en7     17
192.168.1.2/32     link#24            UCS               en7      !
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en7      !
192.168.55         link#14            UCS               en0      !
192.168.55.1/32    link#14            UCS               en0      !
192.168.55.1       d0:96:fb:4d:bf:77  UHLWIir           en0   1199
192.168.55.101/32  link#14            UCS               en0      !
192.168.55.103     ec:41:18:ec:68:78  UHLWI             en0   1200
192.168.55.106     ce:f8:54:7a:df:d8  UHLWI             en0   1068
192.168.55.116     42:6d:b5:1b:32:e8  UHLWIi            en0   1190
192.168.55.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI            en0      !
```

Wifi off:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
127                localhost          UCS               lo0       
localhost          localhost          UH                lo0       
169.254            link#24            UCS               en7      !
192.168.1          link#24            UCS               en7      !
192.168.1.1        84:a9:3e:45:2:78   UHLWIi            en7   1197
192.168.1.2/32     link#24            UCS               en7      !
224.0.0/4          link#24            UmCS              en7      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#24            UCS               en7      !
```

Comment: What's your preference order in the Network CP? Usually setting Ethernet first will enable both. It should then use Enet for most things, unless specifically addressed over wifi.

Comment: Ethernet is first - it has only IP address and mask without gateway (it should have access to directly connected network 192.168.1.X only)